# php, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS)

Tags: php

Hello I know there are a lot of threads like this; I tried and still not working.

It means the: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS) in /var/www/html/public_html/tutorials/mvc/app/controllers/home.php on line 5`

My home.php file:

```
<?php

require_once "core/Controller.php"

class Home extends Controller
{
  public function Index()
  {
    echo 'home/index';
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `require_once "core/Controller.php"` -> missed the semicolon at the end here

Comment: Woah, such fool situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add "**;**" after require_once()